# Detail Text Label Not displaying proper content

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-location

I have an iOS app that loads a feed of posts. The table cell text label displays the post.content. I am trying to get the detailTextLabel to display the post.location and a timestamp. The timestamp works, but the location returns coordinates (0.000, 0.000).
This is the code

```
    - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        Post *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.text = post.content;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"posted on %@ at (%f, %f)", post.timestamp,  (post.location.coordinate.latitude, post.location.coordinate.longitude)];
       }
```

The timestamp is correct, the coordinates are not.
In the post model there is the CLLocation property.
And I declare:

```
static NSString * NSStringFromCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate) {
    return [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
}
```

I fetch nearby posts like so:

```
+ (void)fetchNearbyPosts:(CLLocation *)location
          withBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"lat": @(location.coordinate.latitude),
                                 @"lng": @(location.coordinate.longitude)
                                 };
```

And I update from JSON with this location dictionary

```
NSDictionary *locationDictionary = [dictionary objectForKey:@"location"];
self.location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[locationDictionary valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[[locationDictionary valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]];
```

Between all of this - what is preventing the detailTextLabel from displaying the proper coordinates? I think it is something in the detailTextLabel code-  I am not calling the proper coordinate name so it is returning zero - in fact if I delete the whole post.location.coordinate section, the label returns the exact same thing. I have tried several different ways of expressing the location but most alternatives raise exceptions and this should work shouldn't it?
Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

And this is the actual JSOn - in case you see anything odd in my mapping..

```
[{"content":"Test","postid":1,"lat":"34.13327300486596","lng":"-118.1054221597022", "created_at":"2013-08-06T14:59:42Z"}]
```

Comment: Can you include your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Have you logged post.location.coordinate.latitude and post.location.coordinate.longitude in configureCell:forRowAtIndexPath: to see if they return the correct values?

Comment: @akhalsa I included the method above

Comment: @rdelmar in the log it returns 0.00, 0.00 - so I must not be calling the right thing. Based on the dictionary and json map how would you call it? I'll add the json above

Comment: Work your way backwards until you find the problem. Try logging self.location and locationDictionary. Are either of them giving the correct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"posted on %@ at (%f, %f)",
    post.timestamp,  
    (post.location.coordinate.latitude, post.location.coordinate.longitude)];
```

Remove those extra parenthesis around the latitude and longitude:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"posted on %@ at (%f, %f)",
    post.timestamp, 
    post.location.coordinate.latitude, 
    post.location.coordinate.longitude];
```

Comment: This still returns (0.00, 0.00) which makes me think that the problem might be somewhere else. But I am stumped. The post.timestamp is mapped from the json object "created_at" and that works perfectly. Above I included the location json map - which isn't mapped correctly I assume since it doesn't return the lat/lng which displays in the .json Do you notice anything in the other parts of the code?